# Change theorem color using theorem notes in the amsthm package

Tags: conditionals, theorems, amsthm

When defining a new theorem style in the amsthm package, you can specify what's called (according to http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/latex/thm.pdf) a custom head specification. In there, you can use "#3" to print to screen something specified by the argument. In my case I want to use the argument as a switch. More specifically, I'm writing a document with a series of Math problems and want an easy way to see which have already been done by my students. I want to implement it using newthmstyle so that it would work like this:

```
\begin{problem}
 blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a regular problem

\begin{problem}[done]
 blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a problem, which colors the "problem 5:" part green
```

I know how to do the coloring, it's been tested and it works. I can't figure out how to get the switch to work. If it's considerably easier, it may be a number, instead of "done" that does the switching.

I suppose there needs to be a way to do this, but I'm not proficient enough in Latex's semantics to get it working. I tried some things with the if statements but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you add a complete but [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you tried so far. It makes it much more easier to help you!

Comment: the reference you link looks good, but you may want to also check out the "official" `amsthm` documentation (`amsthdoc.pdf`, on ctan), which was thoroughly revamped last year.  (although it doesn't answer this particular question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\ifstrequal` from `etoolbox` you can test `#3` to get the desired problem head color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% Name of the style
  {\topsep}% Space above
  {\topsep}% Space below
  {}% Body font
  {0pt}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {}% Punctuation after theorem head (in this case empty because defined in the head spec)
  {.5em}% Space after theorem head
  {\ifstrequal{#3}{done}{\color{green}}{}\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2:}}% Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}
  blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a regular problem

\begin{problem}[done]
  blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a problem, which colors the "problem 5:" part green    

\begin{problem}
  blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a regular problem

\begin{problem}[done]
  blah blah
\end{problem} %prints a problem, which colors the "problem 5:" part green    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\parsep` at the top and `\topsep` at the bottom? I believe it should be `\topsep` for both.

Comment: @egreg Corrected!